# how to add a header to a large file in camel?

Tags: apache-camel

I have finally managed to split a large file and reaggregate into smaller (but still very large files)

At the end of the writing I have the count of records in each file. This needs to be added to each of the smaller files as a header.

What is the best way to accomplish this in a performant way ?

Possibilities I considered:

1. Write a file with each header as the split data files are being generated. 
   At the end match up the header and the data file and write concatenate it.

I am running into issues how to read the file in a non polling way and how to trigger the concat phase. This would require re-writing the entire big files

2. keep file headers in a message header or exchange and when all files are written, read all the files from the directory, find a matching header file and add it to output. 
   This would require re-writing the entire big files
3. Add a dummy header with placeholders for the count data and somehow modify the data files in place....
   this seems most performant but not sure how to do this

**Header: 3 records**

a

b

c

Comment: If the files are being split correctly and assuming they are text files and you stored them as a list of strings in the body you could do a simple OGNL notation like `${body.size}`. I have done this before.

Comment: I know the size of the files generated. The question is how to add it to the top line of each of the files ?

Comment: I just concate two arraylists.

Comment: Could you use database to store per file metadata?